# Initiate a vector in R and populate it with values

Tags: r, vector

I am new to R. I have a vector, v, with length 10. I need to create a new vector, F, (with length 11). F should have the following properties: The first element of F should be 100. The second element of F should be 100 * the first element of v. The third element of F should be the second element of F times the second element of v, and so on.

Here is the pseudo-code for this sequence:

F[1] = 100

F[i+1] = F[i] * v[i]

This is very easy to implement in a for loop. But I do not want to use a for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely easy without a for loop too:

```
v <- rnorm(10)
F <- cumprod(c(100, v))
```